# How to passing selected value of DDL from Action to another Action MVC/Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'am trying pass selected value of dropdownlist from one action `(RMA)` which i have my dropdownlist, to another action `(ProcessRequestRMA)` which i want send value of dropdownlist and than save it into database using Ajax.
beacuse of that i make instance of that viewmodel `(OrdreDetails_VM)` which is contains property of dropdown to another viewmodel `(RMAHistory)` which i want to get selected value and save into database, but when i try to save into database i get `Object reference is not set to an instance of an object` (under var RMA = new RMA_History). and its beacuse that property should get selected value its null . its been hours im struggling with this , but still no luck :( 
Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction :)
Thanks in advance :)

OrdreDetails_VM & RMA Action :

```
   public class OrdreDetails_VM
    {  
        public List<SelectListItem> RMAType { set; get; }
        public int SelectedRMAType { set; get; }
    }

    public ActionResult RMA(OrdreDetails_VM oodvm)
    { 
        //DDL
        oodvm.RMAType = new SelectList(data.RMAType, "ID", "RMASager").ToList();

        // do some another stuff
        return View(oodvm);

    }
```

RMAHistory_VM & ProcessRequestRMA :

```
   public class RMAHistory_VM
    {
      public OrdreDetails_VM VM { get; set; }

      public int RMAIDType { get; set; }
      public string RMASager { get; set; }
      public string Kundenavn { get; set; }
      public string Ordrenummer { get; set; }
    }

 public JsonResult ProcessRequestRMA(RMAHistory_VM model) 
 {
            var RMA = new RMA_History // its Modal
             {
                 Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn,
                 Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer,

                 //Expect to get selected value
                 RMATypeID = model.VM.SelectedRMAType

             };

            db.RMA_History.Add(RMA);
            db.SaveChanges();

           return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

  }

 //Here is RMAHistory Modal:
  public class RMA_History
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Kundenavn { get; set; }
      public string Ordrenummer { get; set; }
      public int? RMATypeID { get; set; }
    }
   public RMA_HistoryMap()
            {

           //RMA_History Mapping stuff

            }
```

View:

```
@model NameSpace.OrdreDetails_VM
        //DropDown
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.SelectedRMAType, Model.RMAType, "- Select -", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SelectedRMAType" })

      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>KundeNavn</label>
      <input name="Kundenavn" type="text" id="Kundenavn" class="form-control">

       </div>
      </div>

       <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Ordrenummer</label>
     <input name="Ordrenummer" id="Ordrenummer" type="text" class="form-control" >

       </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btn").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                return myfunction();
            });
    function myfunction() {

    var model = {

    Kundenavn: $("#Kundenavn").val(),
    Ordrenummer: $("#Ordrenummer").val(),
    SelectedRMAType: $("#SelectedRMAType").val()


    }

  $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: "/Account/ProcessRequestRMA",
 dataType: 'json',

 data: {

  Kundenavn: model.Kundenavn,
  Ordrenummer: model.Ordrenummer,

  RMATypeID: model.SelectedRMAType
  },
    success: function (status) {

    if (status) {

   status.Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn;
   status.Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer;

   status.RMATypeID = model.SelectedRMAType;
   console.log("Send");
}
    else {
    alert("Something Wrong");
  }

},

error: function () {
 console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
}
 });
}
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your posting back a value for `SelectedRMAType`,but your `RMAHistory_VM` model does not contain a property named `SelectedRMAType` ( it would need to be `VM.SelectedRMAType` in order to bind). But your code makes no sense - the model in you view should be a model containing properties `List<SelectListItem> RMAType`, `int SelectedRMAType`, `string Kundenavn` and `string Ordrenummer` since that is what you want to submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that your View is not bound to the correct ViewModel. You are saying that your view works with a `OrdreDetails_VM` when it in facts works with a `RMAHistory_VM`. Temporary data, just as the one your `RMAType` property represents, should either go into the same ViewModel when you have one, or as part of the ViewBag when you don't want to create one.

So, let's start by first updating `RMAHistory_VM` to have the required data:

```
public class RMAHistory_VM
{
    public int SelectedRMAType { get; set; }
    public string RMASager { get; set; }
    public string Kundenavn { get; set; }
    public string Ordrenummer { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> RMATypes { set; get; }
}
```

Then, let's throw away `OrdreDetails_VM` and make your view use `RMAHistory_VM` correctly:

```
@model NameSpace.RMAHistory_VM

@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.SelectedRMAType, Model.RMATypes, "- Select -", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SelectedRMAType" })

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>KundeNavn</label>
            <input name="Kundenavn" type="text" id="Kundenavn" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Ordrenummer</label>
            <input name="Ordrenummer" id="Ordrenummer" type="text" class="form-control" >

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that your AJAX call also does not conform to the ViewModel structure (you are even creating an object you are not using), so you have to update it accordingly:

```
function myfunction() {
    var model = {
        Kundenavn: $("#Kundenavn").val(),
        Ordrenummer: $("#Ordrenummer").val(),
        SelectedRMAType: $("#SelectedRMAType").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Account/ProcessRequestRMA",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: model,
        success: function (status) {
            if (status) {
                status.Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn;
                status.Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer;
                status.RMATypeID = model.SelectedRMAType;
                console.log("Send");
            }
            else {
                alert("Something Wrong");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
        }
    });
};
```

And finally update the Action so that it loads `ViewBag.RMATypes`:

```
public ActionResult RMA()
{ 
    //DDL
    var model = new RMAHistory_VM
    {
        RMATypes = new SelectList(data.RMAType, "ID", "RMASager").ToList();
    };

    // do some another stuff
    return View(model);
}
```

You will then have to update how you process the request to match the new ViewModel structure:

```
public JsonResult ProcessRequestRMA(RMAHistory_VM model) 
{
    var RMA = new RMA_History // its Modal
    {
        Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn,
        Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer,
        RMATypeID = model.SelectedRMAType
    };

    db.RMA_History.Add(RMA);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Its a view model! (suggesting OP use `ViewBag` when they have a view model is poor advice)

Comment: @StephenMuecke You have a point there, hadn't thought about it correctly. I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks :) i will try it and i will back to you soon , cuz i have to change and move my viewmodels:)